# FBI PSA on VPNFilter malware

Tags: wireless-networking, router, security, malware

Is there a way to tell what routers this would apply to?
Also would merely rebooting or even changing password be effective?

https://www.ic3.gov/media/2018/180525.aspx

> FOREIGN CYBER ACTORS TARGET HOME AND OFFICE ROUTERS AND NETWORKED
>   DEVICES WORLDWIDE SUMMARY The FBI recommends any owner of small office
>   and home office routers power cycle (reboot) the devices. Foreign
>   cyber actors have compromised hundreds of thousands of home and office
>   routers and other networked devices worldwide. The actors used
>   VPNFilter malware to target small office and home office routers. The
>   malware is able to perform multiple functions, including possible
>   information collection, device exploitation, and blocking network
>   traffic.
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS The size and scope of the infrastructure impacted by
>   VPNFilter malware is significant. The malware targets routers produced
>   by several manufacturers and network-attached storage devices by at
>   least one manufacturer. The initial infection vector for this malware
>   is currently unknown.
>
> THREAT VPNFilter is able to render small office and home office
>   routers inoperable. The malware can potentially also collect
>   information passing through the router. Detection and analysis of the
>   malware’s network activity is complicated by its use of encryption and
>   misattributable networks.
>
> DEFENSE The FBI recommends any owner of small office and home office
>   routers reboot the devices to temporarily disrupt the malware and aid
>   the potential identification of infected devices. Owners are advised
>   to consider disabling remote management settings on devices and secure
>   with strong passwords and encryption when enabled. Network devices
>   should be upgraded to the latest available versions of firmware.

Comment: Your quoted text says exactl what to do in the Defense section.

Comment: @Moab -Thanks.  My question was more about how effective the recommendation actions might be.  Verizon's says their routers almost never offer firmware updates as router vendors prefer to sell new routers.

Comment: They look like the most effective things to do, reboot router and apply patched firmware to prevent this from happening again.